# Llenar varias tablas temporales con los queries de un solo SP en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, tablas

hay manera de hacer algo como esto:

**insert into TABLA_TEMP1, TABLA_TEMP2...  exec MI_SP @PARAM1="PARAM1"**

En otras palabras, q un SP pueda llenar varias tablas temporales??

Quedo atento a sus comentarios... gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes declarar las tablas fuera y llenarlas dentro, sin ningún problema.

```
Create procedure mi_sp2 @param1 varchar(100)
As
Begin
    Insert into #temp1(id, nombre)
    Values
    (1,Concat('tabla 1 ',@param1));

    Insert into #temp2 (id, nombre)
    Values
    (1,Concat('tabla 2 ',@param1));
        
End
```

Fíjate que en `dbo.mi_sp2`, insertamos valores, en tablas que no están definidas.

```
Create procedure mi_Sp1
As
Begin

    Create table #temp1(id int, nombre varchar(100));
    Create table #temp2(id int, nombre varchar(100));

    exec dbo.mi_Sp2 'param1';

    Select * from #temp1;
    Select * from #temp2;

end
```

Pero las definimos en `dbo.mi_Sp1`, que como engloba al otro procedure, se encarga de crearlas y de retornar su salida.

```
EXEC dbo.mi_Sp1;
```

[image: Res1]